# Unable to install php-gd with php8.1 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, gd

If I try to run anything like `apt install php8.1-gd` or `php8-gd` or php-gd I run into the same error, which says E: Package 'php-blabla' has no installation candidate

System info:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- PHP 8.1.17
- Running in docker container

Packages I've tried so far: `apt-get install libgd3`, `apt install php8.1-gd`, `apt install php8.2-gd`, `apt install php8.0-gd`, `apt install php8-gd`, `apt-get install php_gd2`

Has anyone an idea how to fix my problem?

Comment: try `apt update` before running install command. in another words: your local package database is old you need to update it.

Comment: I've already done so.. unfortunately didn't change anything

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please share the whole `Dockerfile` that you use. So that other people can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Currently the Docker is running a official php:8.1-apache image. Drupal was installed via composer. Do you need any more information?

Comment: _"As of docker-library/php#542, this image blocks the installation of Debian's PHP packages."_ You should probably be using `docker-php-ext-install`. [Read this](https://hub.docker.com/_/php#:~:text=E%3A%20Package%20%27php%2DXXX%27%20has%20no%20installation%20candidate)